# using soap with vbs on 64 bit

Tags: c#, soap, vbscript

Following code is not able to create instance on windows 2012 R2 64 bit to make soap call via vbs

```
Dim obj
Set obj = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
```

Few articles mentioned that, SOAP Toolkits have been replaced by the Microsoft .NET Framework.  What shall I do to so that it may call web service & can run as scheduled job on win 2012 R2 64 bit environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating [a windows service using .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order to execute a task periodically. Then you could follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819935.aspx) to make the web service call using .NET.

If you are not familiar with .NET and you insist on VB Script, you could follow [this tutorial](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/deed3efb-1e11-4e7e-8bfd-96a981de5c35) which handles the SOAP requests in a very structured way, wrapping the whole functionality in classes.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks Pantelis Natsiavas. I'm familiar with .net & decided to use windows service. I need more info as never used SOAP in the past. App has a service with various web methods exposed. Methods returns void, int & xmldocument. What shall be my procedure in provided tutorial to make web service call?

Comment: Glad to help. You should upvote the answer in order to make things easier for other users bumping in your question... Anyway, isn't [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819935.aspx) helpful? It's a link on my answer. You would have to implement the SOAP client part...